# The app I created won't allow me to save pictures?

Tags: java, android, android-camera

The app is allowing me to capture pictures, then allowing me to accept or reject pictures, showing me accepted images inside the app but not saving them to the device. All help much appreciated?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button takePictureButton;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private Uri file;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        takePictureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_image);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            takePictureButton.setEnabled(false);
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE }, 0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                takePictureButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    }

    public void takePicture(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        file = Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile());
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, file);

        startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
    }

    private static File getOutputMediaFile(){
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "Demo");

        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("Demo", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        return new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                    "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
    }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (requestCode == 100) {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    imageView.setImageURI(file);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the right storage permissions.

I suggest you to move the image and then rename it;